# How to set value of *ngFor dynamically in Angular2

Tags: html, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I want to set the value of '*ngFor' dynamically.

I have a div like : `<div *ngFor="let section of anyArr; let i = index">`

I want upper statement like this :

```
<div *ngFor="let section of {{anyArr}}; let i = index">`
```

I want 'dummyArr' as anyArr = myArr[0].Control[2] from .ts file. 
Is this possible in Angular 2 ???

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using getter in your component like this:

```
get anyArr() {
  return myArr[0].Control[2];
}
```

Then in template use:

```
<div *ngFor="let section of anyArr; let i = index">`
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question... get anyArr() is just another function in component, and you can invoke it from template.